# Microsoft Visio | How to perform VSTO (or alternative) from a Server

Tags: vsto, visio

**Objective:**

1. I have a Web Application.
2. I have some Microsoft Visio files present in my Application.
3. I want to process (edit/export/print) these Visio files (Note: Opensource tools like LibreOffice Draw are not giving the same quality like Visio)

**Current Progress:** I got to know about Microsoft VSTO and achieved some basic operation by using VSTO

Sample code of VSTO

```
string docPath = "input.vsdx";

this.Application.Documents.Open(docPath);

int pageIndex = 1;
Visio.Pages visioDocPages = this.Application.ActiveDocument.Pages;
if (pageIndex <= visioDocPages.Count) {
    // Use `visioDocPages[pageIndex]` for some processing
}


this.Application.ActiveDocument.Close();
```

**Queries:**

1. VSTO seems to be an Automation library, so I fear it will fail when multiple files needs to be processed from a Server
2. Are there any other methods to work on visio (like edit, export, print, etc) from a Server environment
3. Am looking for either officail Microsoft packages OR Open Source ones (NOT looking for paid packages like https://products.aspose.com/diagram/net/)

Comment: Microsoft forum post: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-learn/microsoft-visio-how-to-perform-vsto-or-alternative-from-a-server/td-p/2777052#.YUwII_cM4vg.link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSTO is a layer on top of the COM addin API useful only for developing Office addins. It cannot be used from external applications.

No Office applications (Visio included) can be used from a service (such as IIS). Look at the Open XML API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/how-to-manipulate-the-visio-file-format-programmatically) - it will let you manipulate vsdx files without Visio.

Comment: Ya I did have a look at Open XML API, it lacks App specific capabilites likes export. and open source app like LibreOffice export Visio with some minor mistakes.